# How to reduce token expiration time from 1 hr to 30 min

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I know when we create tokens default token lifetime is 1 hour but I want to change that to 30 minutes.

I want to make tokens available for only 30 minutes to users. For any resource `Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph` gives token available for 60 minutes.

With this token, users can call graph only within 1 hour. Now I want to make it to reduce to 30 minutes so that after that they have to request new token or the old token should not work.

How to do that? Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

The default lifetime of an access token is variable. When issued, the default lifetime of an access token is assigned a random value ranging between **60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average)**.

Lifetime of an access token can be adjusted to control how often the client application expires the application session, and how often it requires the user to reauthenticate (either silently or interactively).

> How to do that? Anyone tried this before?

To override the default access token lifetime variation, set a static default access token lifetime by using Configurable token lifetime (CTL).

A token lifetime policy is a type of policy object that contains token lifetime rules. This policy controls how long access, SAML, and ID tokens for this resource are considered valid. Token lifetime policies cannot be set for refresh and session tokens. If no policy is set, the system enforces the default lifetime value.

Refer to these documentations for more information:

- On Creating [Configurable token lifetime prolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties)
- Access token lifetime refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#access-token-lifetime).

Comment: I followed those documents, still getting token valid for 1 hour. Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595618/default-token-lifetime-not-changing-for-my-service-principal

Comment: @user000682 Thanks for your response I have updated the other thread with my answer and able to limit the access token life time of service principal to 30 minutes