# Default token lifetime not changing for my service principal

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-policy, azure-service-principal

I want to make tokens available for only 30 minutes to users. This is doable if we configure token lifetime policy but it's not working as I still get tokens valid for 1 hour.

Followed this suggested documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:30:00"}}') -DisplayName "Valid 30min" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"

# Get ID of the service principal
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '<service principal display name>'"

# Assign policy to a service principal
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id
```

How to make tokens valid for only 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created the Policy by using below commands:

```bash
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:30:00"}}') -DisplayName "Valid 30min" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '<service principal display name>'"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id
```

[image]

To add the Policy to the Service Principal, I used the below commands:

```bash
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'ServicePricipalName'"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id

Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject -id PolicyID
```

[image]

After adding the Policy, I generated the token for the Azure Service Principal but the Token lifetime Policy failed.

**The access token got generated with 1 hour of expiration time:**

[image]

**To fix the issue** try creating the Token lifetime Policy by changing the value for **`IsOrganizationDefault`** as **$True** like below:

```bash
$policytest = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:30:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

[image]

**I am able to get the token successfully with `30` mins of expiration time.**

[image]

If the issue still persists, check if the policy is not overridden by a policy with a higher priority.

Comment: creating the Token lifetime Policy by changing the value for IsOrganizationDefault as $True is making all service principals in my organization to generate tokens valid for 30 minutes but my usecase is for only one service principal not all service principals in my tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same documentation steps and tested this in my local environment, and I am able to set the access token lifetime of the service principal to 30 minutes.

Step 1: Created a configure lifetime token policy to one of the sp with life time as 30 minutes as shown below.

[image]

Step 2 : created the access token from the postman and validated the expiry time of the access token through [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) as shown below.

[image]

There were couple of policy Evalution restriction and prioritization rule for this policy refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#policy-evaluation-and-prioritization) for more information on them.

Comment: I too followed the same documentation and same powershell script but it is still giving me token valid for 1 hour when IsOrganizationDefault is $False and also in your last image I can see token expires in 1199 seconds which means around 20 minutes and after decoding also it's showing 20 minutes but you set the access token lifetime of the service principal to 30 minutes in powershell script, Why it's giving token valid for only 20 minutes where you set 30 minutes in PS script?

Comment: @user000682 Post man says that my token will get expired in 20 minutes but when i decode the same token using jwt.ms as shown in the image it is showing that it will expire in 30 minutes