# Increase access token lifetime in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have a multi-tenant azure app that is authorized by the clients using Authorization code flow. The access token I get from the flow has a TTL of 1 hour on average whereas refresh token has 90 days. I am using this access token on behalf of the users to fetch some of their resources. Can I increase the access token lifetime? I am playing around with [Configure token lifetime policies (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes). However, I am not sure if this should be done by me (azure app tenant) or by the clients (in their tenant).

Comment: Do you want to assign the lifetime policy to only one service principal or all the service principals?

Comment: @Rukmini Not sure about the concept of service principals. I want to increase the lifetime of the token I get from the authorization code flow.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595618/default-token-lifetime-not-changing-for-my-service-principal/74596939#74596939? and you need to configure policy in your Azure App tenant by signing in as Global Admin.

Comment: @Rukmini I was able to configure a policy and got a token with increased lifetime. This was for a user which resides on the same tenant as the azure app. I tried with another user from a different tenant and for that user, the token did not have an extended lifetime. Is it something configurable?

Comment: check if the policy is not overridden by a policy with a higher priority

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application:

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Policy for 2 hours in the Parent Tenant** (*where the Azure AD App resides*) and token generated successfully with 2 hours lifetime:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read 
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

But when I tried another user from a different tenant the token did not have an extended lifetime (2 hours).

[image]

After the first login to the Azure Multi-Tenant Application by another tenant user, the Application will be added in **Azure Enterprise Application in another tenant** like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to add **Azure AD Token Lifetime Policy** for another Tenant like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "DisplayName eq 'rukmt'"
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id>'"
```

[image]

*For both the Azure Tenants the Azure Token Lifetime Policy has been applied by using the same application.*

***I tried to generate token using the second Tenant User:***

[image]

The **token successfully got generated with 2 hours of Token Lifetime** like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check if the policy is overridden by a policy with a higher priority.

Comment: I tried this. I have two token flows- client credential and authorization code flow in the same app. After configuring the policy, the token I get from client credential flow gets extended lifetime, but the other doesn't.  How do we check the priority? I have gone through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#policy-evaluation-and-prioritization and believe my policy has the highest priority.

Comment: I checked authorization code flow and I can see extended token lifetime without any issue as updated in the answer. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/QGStQ9y.png).