# from okta auth0 how can i increase the azure ad token validity?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, auth0, okta

I'm using Okta as the identity provider for user management and have integrated Azure AD with Auth0 for authentication. However, when i retrieve user information after authentication using this API of auth0

```
url = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/api/v2/users/' + user_id
```

I notice that the providers access token remains the same each time I call the API.
Is there a way to get different token. If not, then how can i increase the expiry time of provider access token
as My auth0 expiry time is 72hr and azure ad is 1hr.

I have used this but it didn't help me :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-and-assign-it-to-a-service-principal

Comment: yes i tried. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-and-assign-it-to-a-service-principal this . the process run successfully but didn't update the token expiry time.
I also look for a solution of getting refresh token with the access token , so I could at least request for a new access token if token expires but still not progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the token lifetime of the Azure AD access token, you can make use of Microsoft Graph Explorer or PowerShell:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"23:59:59\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": true
}
```

[image]

For **sample**, I generated access token and the token lifetime is 24 hours:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

**Note** that: The Azure AD access token lifetime can be set withing 10 mins to 24 hours.

- You can assign the token lifetime policy to a Service Principal instead of whole organization. Check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-and-assign-it-to-a-service-principal)
- You can also make use of below PowerShell script instead of Microsoft Graph Explorer. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/new-mgpolicytokenlifetimepolicy?view=graph-powershell-1.0#example-1-code-snippet)
- Make sure to have **`Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration`** permission consented to perform the action.

Comment: hi. thanx for the your response . i tried this method of creating the tokenLifetimePolicies and then assigning it to the principal, but the token i generate after that was still have 1hr expiry time. The difference which i can see is I'm using auth0 to get third party provider token(azure) . which validity is of 1 hr. I created the policy with global administrator user

Comment: Did you set "isOrganizationDefault": true?

Comment: no. what is the use of it .

Comment: Try setting "isOrganizationDefault": true and check it sets for organization level

Comment: @sandeepnegi then regenerate the access token and check

Comment: what if i'm using other directory . then how can I set it for them. I have to manually register app first then get its app object id and then set the policy?

Comment: Yes check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143369/increase-access-token-lifetime-in-azure-ad

Comment: is there any UI interface to add this tokenLifetimePolicies to app

Comment: AFAIK it's not there